# An issue with Aurelia CLI using Webpack and 'script-loader'

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I created a new CLI project using Webpack to try to come to grips with Webpack.

I've 'npm installed' the Webpack '[script-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader)' to load a file that contains nothing more than `console.log("Hello World")`. This due to the fact that my ultimate goal in another project will involve having to load a JS/JQuery file in this way.

When I run the site, the log script never executes and no errors occur. By my limited understanding, 'script-loader' should insert the script into every page causing the log every time a page is loaded.

Here is my webpack.config.js. Note it should be the default the CLI creates with the exception of: `{ test: /[\/\\]src[\/\\]helloworld\.js$/, loader: 'script-loader' },`

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const project = require('./aurelia_project/aurelia.json');
const { AureliaPlugin, ModuleDependenciesPlugin } = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');
const { ProvidePlugin } = require('webpack');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');

// config helpers:
const ensureArray = (config) => config && (Array.isArray(config) ? config : [config]) || [];
const when = (condition, config, negativeConfig) =>
  condition ? ensureArray(config) : ensureArray(negativeConfig);

// primary config:
const title = 'Aurelia Navigation Skeleton';
const outDir = path.resolve(__dirname, project.platform.output);
const srcDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const nodeModulesDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
const baseUrl = '/';

const cssRules = [
  { loader: 'css-loader' },
];

module.exports = ({production, server, extractCss, coverage, analyze} = {}) => ({
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    modules: [srcDir, 'node_modules'],
  },
  entry: {
    app: ['aurelia-bootstrapper'],
    vendor: ['bluebird'],
  },
  mode: production ? 'production' : 'development',
  output: {
    path: outDir,
    publicPath: baseUrl,
    filename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js' : '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.map' : '[name].[hash].bundle.map',
    chunkFilename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js' : '[name].[hash].chunk.js'
  },
  performance: { hints: false },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: outDir,
    // serve index.html for all 404 (required for push-state)
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  devtool: production ? 'nosources-source-map' : 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      // CSS required in JS/TS files should use the style-loader that auto-injects it into the website
      // only when the issuer is a .js/.ts file, so the loaders are not applied inside html templates
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        issuer: [{ not: [{ test: /\.html$/i }] }],
        use: extractCss ? ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: cssRules
        }) : ['style-loader', ...cssRules],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        issuer: [{ test: /\.html$/i }],
        // CSS required in templates cannot be extracted safely
        // because Aurelia would try to require it again in runtime
        use: cssRules
      },
      { test: /\.html$/i, loader: 'html-loader' },
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
      { test: /\.json$/i, loader: 'json-loader' },
      { test: /[\/\\]src[\/\\]helloworld\.js$/, loader: 'script-loader' },
      // use Bluebird as the global Promise implementation:
      { test: /[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]bluebird[\/\\].+\.js$/, loader: 'expose-loader?Promise' },
      // embed small images and fonts as Data Urls and larger ones as files:
      { test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|cur)$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 8192 } },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 10000, mimetype: 'application/font-woff2' } },
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 10000, mimetype: 'application/font-woff' } },
      // load these fonts normally, as files:
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|otf)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'file-loader' },
      ...when(coverage, {
        test: /\.[jt]s$/i, loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
        include: srcDir, exclude: [/\.{spec,test}\.[jt]s$/i],
        enforce: 'post', options: { esModules: true },
      })
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new AureliaPlugin(),
    new ProvidePlugin({
      'Promise': 'bluebird'
    }),
    new ModuleDependenciesPlugin({
      'aurelia-testing': [ './compile-spy', './view-spy' ]
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.ejs',
      metadata: {
        // available in index.ejs //
        title, server, baseUrl
      }
    }),
    ...when(extractCss, new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: production ? '[contenthash].css' : '[id].css',
      allChunks: true
    })),
    ...when(production, new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: 'static/favicon.ico', to: 'favicon.ico' }])),
    ...when(analyze, new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
  ]
});
```

Is my usage or my understanding wrong about how to accomplish my goal?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to import your scripts somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

@rabah-g is correct.

I overlooked the import statement. The webpack.config.js is correct as it is.

I'm using TypeScript and a JS file that isn't a module. In order to get it to work, I just had to add:

`import 'helloworld.js';`

To the top of the model for the view I wanted it to be added to.